# docker-compose stop not working after docker-compose -p <name> up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose version 2. I am starting containers with `docker-compose -p some_name up -d` and trying to kill them with `docker-compose stop`. The commands exits with `0` code but the containers are still up and running.

Is this the expected behaviour for version? If yes, any idea how can I work around it?

my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
      xpack.security.enabled: "false"
      xpack.monitoring.enabled: "false"
      xpack.graph.enabled: "false"
      xpack.watcher.enabled: "false"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 262144
        hard: 262144

  kafka-server:
    image: spotify/kafka
    environment:
      - TOPICS=my-topic
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"

  test:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka-server
```

**update**

I found that the problem is caused by using the `-p` parameter and giving explicit prefix to the container. Still looking for the best way to solve it.

Comment: The expected behaviour is that after `docker-compose stop` your containers will be stopped. Please, post your `docker-compose.yml` and output of `docker-compose stop` command.

Comment: the `docker-compose stop` command gives no output. I updated the question

Comment: also are you sure that this the default behaviour? can you reference some documentation?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/

Comment: Which is correct for the case when containers are not started in detached mode but apparently not true for when containers are started on the backgroun with the `-d` arg. Hence the question.

Comment: No, it stops docker-compose containers if they're in detached mode too. I've just tested it.

Comment: aha, that was helpfull, I updated the question

Answer (score 13):

`docker-compose -p [project_name] stop` worked in my case. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing running containers to stop by sending a `SIGKILL` with `docker-compose -p some_name kill`.

[docker-compose kill](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/kill/)

I just read and experimented with something from [compose CLI envs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) when passing `-p`.

You have to pass the `-p some_name` to `kill` the containers or `compose` will assume the directory name if you don't.

Kindly let me know if this helped.

Comment: same thing. all containers are still active and command exits with zero exit code

Comment: `docker kill elasticsearch; docker kill kafka-server; docker kill test`

Comment: any idea why the `docker-compose stop` command is not working?

Comment: additionally `docker kill <service_name>` is not working

Comment: ```docker -p <docker-compose-name> down``` did it for me